# Calling JQuery when textbox had been change doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want textbox to automatic call jQuery when the text/value changed. At the start, the readonly owner textbox is empty. I only can select the name and then it will automatic paste the name to `tbAdd_Powner` textbox. After it pasted, I want it to automatic call it jQuery to get value from `tbAdd_Powner` textbox and pass it to `txtPass` textbox. For example, I select Joe then it will paste Joe in `tbAdd_Powner textbox` then it call jQuery to pass Joe to `txtPass` textbox.

I tried the codes below and it doesn't work.

Here is jQuery and html example,

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testtest.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="testtest" EnableEventValidation="false" Async="true" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>



    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {

    $('#tbAdd_Powner').on('input',function () {
    alert("It Changed!");
    $('#txtPass').val($('#tbAdd_Powner').val());
 });

});        </script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbAdd_Powner" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" Width="163px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: yes, JQuery link is stored in ~/Site.master. I edited it above.

Comment: The call for changing tbAdd_Powner text after selecting Joe, can this also change the value of txtPass so there doesn't have to be an extra jQuery call or is there a reason to not do this?

Comment: You are right but I have a reason because later, instead of Joe, it will assign phonenumber to txtPass. So I want to make JQuery work first then I can do the rest of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031826/jquery-change-function-not-working-with-dynamically-populated-select-list  This may help

Comment: Isn't it better to use only jQuery? You're mixing a jQuery event and set using a regular javascript DOM setting.

Comment: I edited to JQuery only. BTW, I use IE8

Comment: Hmm. Lots of downvotes, no explanations.

Comment: Could you please show us the input `textName`? It would also help if you were to use a consistent naming convention, it is not important to the operation of the code but it is a good habit to get into. For instance you have used 'text', 'tb' and 'txt' as text box prefixes in one form.

Comment: My apology, I edited it wrong before and now I clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the ID is not the same as what you have thanks to .NET renaming them.

You need to do the same thing you do inside with `<%=tbAdd_Powner.ClientID%>'`

AKA:

```
$('#<%=tbAdd_Powner.ClientID%>').on(...
```

Other options would be use a class, partial selector, or Static option in the .NET code.

Comment: Another option is to set `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds for me like you need `input`. Also, don't mix jQuery with pure JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  $('#tbAdd_Powner').on('input', function () {
       $('#<%=txtPass.ClientID%>').val($('#<%=tbAdd_Powner.ClientID%>').val());
  });
});
```

I don't know what values have `ClientID`, but you may need `#` selector to select the element by id.

See which is [the difference between `input` and `change`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17047497/1420197).

Comment: I tried this example, it never fire at all because I added alert in tbadd_Powner function and it never alert. I use `$('#tbAdd_Powner').on('input',function () {
        alert("It Changed!");
        $('#txtPass').val($('#tbAdd_Powner').val();`

Comment: @StudentIT What value `txtPass.ClientID` has? Do you have any errors in the page? Maybe the element doesn't exist.

Comment: The value for `txtPass` is empty. There is not error in the page.

Comment: @StudentIT Not the input value but the `txtPass.ClientID`'s value. I am not familiar with ASP .NET but I guess you need to see what `id` the input has (use browser web inspector to see it).