# How to dynamically check if select field has data

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `select` field that is populated with data after a callback succeeded and I need to call a function when this happens.

I tried to use the jQuery `on .change` but this is fired only after I select another option, not when the select field is populated.

Is there a way to dynamically check if a `select` field gets some values?

This is what I've done so far:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   // Do something
});
```

This is how I populate my select list (I'm using google apps script):

```
  function onMetricsSuccess(selectList) {
    $.each(selectList, function(key, value) {   
      $('select')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value",value)
        .text(value)); 
      });
  }
```

Comment: how did you populate your select list?

Comment: Maybe you can do it similiar to this answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031826/jquery-change-function-not-working-with-dynamically-populated-select-list]

Comment: Tried it but it still doesn't do anything when the select list is populated

Comment: @PavelValeriu i added and example in my answer. Just click Run code snippet button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

> Note:I added an ID to apply the event to specific select

// After populating the select list

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#myDropdown').on('change', function(){
      alert('Yay I was changed !!');
    });
    populateSelect();
});


function populateSelect(){
  var select = $('#myDropdown');
   select.append(new Option('Im a text', 'text'));
   select.append(new Option('Im a number', 'number'));
  
   $('#myDropdown').trigger('change');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="myDropdown"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I need to call the `populateSelect()` function only after the select list is populated...right now it is called when the page loads even if there is no value in the select list

Comment: @PavelValeriu this is an example only since I don't know how you populated the list, so in your case just move this line `$('#myDropdown').trigger('change');` on the end of onMetricsSuccess function

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the dropdown options are populated or not try this:

```
var length = $('#mySelectList').children('option').length;
if(length > 0)
{
   // populated successfully
}
```